# Cannot require AMD module inside a registerSuite Intern.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amd, intern

I have some code that I want to require:

```
define(function(require)
{
    return stuff {
        my_func: function()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    };
});
```

I try to require it inside a registerSuite.

```
registerSuite(function()
{
    var navigation = require('path/to/navigation.js');

    'my test': function()
    {
        return navigation.my_func();
    }
});
```

This gives me an error of "my_func()" is not found in navigation. I had to convert the "include" code into a class and instantiate an object to get it to work. Is there a reason the require-way isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When loading an AMD module, the AMD `require` function expects a module identifier, not a file path, so you would use:

```
var navigation = require('something/navigation');
```

where 'something' is the package containing your module, and the module name doesn't end with '.js'. You can also use a relative identifier, like

```
var navigation = require('../navigation');
```